# Datepicker minDate today and maxDate 31 Dec Next year

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Try to limit the date selection between today and 31st Dec of next year.

```
$(function() {
  $('.public-holiday-date-pick').datepicker({ 
    minDate: '0',
    yearRange: '-0:+1',
    maxDate: ???
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true
  });
});
```

How should I define maxDate ? tried few things like '31 12 +1', or just 'last day of next year', did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) First get today's using

```
var today = new Date();
```

2) Similarly set the **`lastDate`** as below

```
var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear() +1, 11, 31);
```

The value in `lastDate` will be like

> **`lastDate = 31 December, today's year +1`**

Finally set the **`lastDate`** as **`maxDate`**

```
var today = new Date();  //Get today's date
var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear() +1, 11, 31);  //To get the 31st Dec of next year
$(function() {
  $('.public-holiday-date-pick').datepicker({ 
    minDate: '0',
    yearRange: '-0:+1',
    maxDate: lastDate, //set the lastDate as maxDate
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true
  });
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/LJ93d/)

Comment: It worked for me but why 11, 31 ? I thought it should be 12, 31

Comment: @AskandLearn Actually `getMonth` returns numeric value beginning with 0.  `*Example:* jan=0, feb=1, march=2....Dec=11`  Hence I have used 11.  *If you try using 12 then it will move on to jan, 2015.*  Hope you can understand.

Comment: @AskandLearn Glad to hear that I was able to help :)