# How to restrict age minimum 3 years in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How to restrict age to  3 years from the current date it should not exceed more than 5 years and it should not select future date(Theme is Date of birth should be 3 to 5 years not more than or less than that) how to do this in the below date picker code, is this possible to do in bootstrap validation

Example The Current Year is 2017 he can select from 2014 to 2012 not more means he should not select either 2011 or 2018

My Fiddle Link:  https://jsfiddle.net/k2e3eyhm/1/

```js
$('#studentDOB').datepicker({
   autoclose : true,
   format : 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        }).on('changeDate',function(e) {
 $('#studentEnrollmentForm').bootstrapValidator(
 'revalidateField', 'studentDOB');
 });             
              
/*'studentDTO.studentDOB' : {
    validators : {
     notEmpty : {
  message : 'The date is required',
   },
  date : {
   format : 'MM/DD/YYYY',
   message : 'The date is not a valid',
   min: '01/01/1999'
   }
  }
 }*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="col-sm-6" style="height: 75px;">
 <div class='col-md-5'>
   <div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group input-append date" id="studentDOB">
     <input type="Text" class="form-control" name="studentDOB" /> 
              <span class="input-group-addon add-on">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: read out the article : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086584/datepicker-mindate-today-and-maxdate-31-dec-next-year

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lp0s2471/

```
var today = new Date();
var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear() -5, 11, 31);
$(function() {
  $('.how_old_are_you').datepicker({ 
    yearRange: '-0:+1',
    maxDate: lastDate,
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true
  });
});
```

Comment: $(function() {
      
      
      
      $('#teacherDateOfBirth').datepicker({
         
         format : 'mm/dd/yyyy',
         startDate : '-5y',
         endDate : '+0d',
         
         autoclose : true
        
        })
        .on('change',function() {
           
            
     $('#teacherSelfForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'teacherDOB');
           

          });
     });
    });

Comment: i had written like this check why this is not working

Comment: I think the code snippet is just 'funny' I tried jsfiddle  + locally and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/Lp0s2471/1/